Mellin Transform of $\frac{1}{x^4+1}$ for $0<s<4$
While reviewing contour integration, I found the following question: prove that if $0<s<4$ then
$$
   \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{x^4+1}dx=\frac{\pi}{8\sin(\frac{\pi s}{4})}
$$
This seemed like an easy enough integral to evaluate using residues. I considered the following contour $\gamma$
$\gamma$ in pink with the segments $\gamma_r$, $\gamma_R$, and $\gamma_v$ referred to below." />
Now, I can estimate that for $r<1$ and $R>1$ we have (by the ML inequality) that
$$
    \left|\int_{\gamma_r}f(z) dz\right| \leq \frac{r^s}{1-r^4}, \quad \left|\int_{\gamma_R}f(z) dz\right| \leq \frac{R^s}{R^4-1}
$$
hence
$$
    \lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\int_{\gamma_r}f(z) dz=\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\gamma_R}f(z) dz= 0
$$
Moreover, by parameterizing the integral we can see that
$$
    \int_{\gamma_v}f(z)dz = ie^{\frac{\pi is}{2}} \int_0^\infty f(x)dx
$$
Then the residue theorem implies that
$$
    \int_\gamma f(z) dz =2\pi i \operatorname{Res}(f,e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}) = -\frac{\pi i}{2}e^{\frac{\pi is}{4}}
$$
and putting this together with the above reasoning we see that
$$
    \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{x^4+1}dx=-\frac{\pi i}{2(1+ie^{\frac{\pi is}{2}})}e^{\frac{\pi is}{4}}
$$
It seems that all is left is some algebraic manipulation, but I cannot seem to work it out myself. Any hint would be much appreciated.

I think that $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{x^4+1}dx=\frac{\pi}{4\sin(\frac{\pi s}{4})}$

It may be easier to note that
$$
\newcommand{\M}[2]{\mathcal{M} \left{ #1 \right} \left( #2 \right)}
\M{f(x^c)}{s}
= \frac{1}{|c|} \M{f}{\frac s c}
$$
provided that $\M{f}{s}$ converges for $\mathfrak{Re}(s) \in (\alpha,\beta)$ and $c \ne 0$, in which case the fundamental strip for the above is given by
$
\frac{\mathfrak{Re}(s)}{c} \in (\alpha,\beta)
$.
And then noting that
$$
\M{\frac{1}{1+x^2}}{s} = \frac{\pi}{2 \sin \frac{\pi s}{2}} \text{ if } \mathfrak{Re}(s) \in (0,2)
$$
the initial property with $c=2$ allows an easy conclusion, in line with the previous comment.

If you substitute $x=e^{t/2}$ and use symmetry to get an integral over $t\in (0,\infty)$, this integral is equivalent to the one found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/241922/137524.
