# Zeta function values in terms of Bernoulli numbers.

Tags: riemann-zeta

The material presented  at this link on [Zeta function  values at even
integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240993/) proposes a
method to compute these that is based on Euler's work. I would like to
present a short  proof for your consideration (the goal  being to keep
it as simple  as possible) and I'd be grateful  to get confirmation of
its correctness/admissibility e.g.  by giving a reference.

We seek to prove that

$$\zeta(2n) = \sum_{m\ge1} \frac{1}{m^{2n}} =
(-1)^{n+1} \frac{B_{2n} 2^{2n}}{2(2n)!} \pi^{2n}$$

where $B_{2n}$ are Bernoulli numbers. Rewrite this as

$$\zeta(2n) = - \frac{1}{2} (2\pi i)^{2n} \frac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!}.$$

Now           using           the           method           presented
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211372/) we introduce

$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{z^{2n}} \pi \cot(\pi z)$$

and compute the integral of $f(z)$ along a circle of radius $R$ in the
complex plane,  where $R$  goes to infinity.  We certainly  have $|\pi
\cot(\pi z)|<2\pi$  for $z$ on  the circle  and $R$ large  enough. The
term $1/z^{2n}$ is  $\Theta(1/R^{2n})$ so that the  integral along the
circle is $\Theta(1/R^{2n-1})$ and vanishes in the limit.

Using the Cauchy Residue theorem we thus obtain
$$ 2 \zeta(2n) + \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} f(z) =
\lim_{R\to\infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=R} f(z) dz = 0.$$

The conclusion is that

$$ \zeta(2n) = - \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} f(z)$$

For the  exponential generating function  of the Bernoulli  numbers we
have

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty B_m \frac{t^m}{m!} = \frac{t}{e^t-1}$$

so that

$$ \sum_{m=0}^\infty B_{2m} \frac{t^{2m}}{(2m)!} =
\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{t}{e^t-1} - \frac{t}{e^{-t}-1}\right) =
\frac{1}{2} t \frac{e^{t/2}+e^{-t/2}}{e^{t/2}-e^{-t/2}}.$$

Setting $t=2\pi i z$, we obtain

$$ \sum_{m=0}^\infty B_{2m} (2\pi i)^{2m} \frac{z^{2m}}{(2m)!} =
\pi i z \frac{e^{\pi i z}+e^{-\pi i z}}{e^{\pi i z}-e^{-\pi i z}} = 
\pi z \cot(\pi z).$$

Putting it all together, we find
$$\zeta(2n) = - \frac{1}{2} [z^{-1}] f(z) = 
- \frac{1}{2} [z^{2n-1}] \pi \cot(\pi z) = 
- \frac{1}{2} [z^{2n}]  \pi z \cot(\pi z) \\ =
- \frac{1}{2} (2\pi i)^{2n} \frac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!},$$

where  $[z^q]$  is  the  coefficient  extraction  operator  for  power
series. This concludes the proof.

**Addendum Jul 12  2018.** As remarked upon in the  comments the bound
does not work with a circle of  radius $R$ even if passing between the
poles. The reader of this post  is invited to observe that the correct
mechanics is to use a rectangle

$$\Gamma =\pm (N+1/2) \pm i N$$

with $N$ a  large positive integer. The vertical  segments pass midway
between the poles. We show that the integral vanishes on two of these,
with the other  two being done similarly. We use  two lines $\Gamma_1$
which is $N+1/2\pm  iN$ (right vertical) and $\Gamma_2$  which is $\pm
(N+1/2)+iN$ (top horizontal).  Now on $\Gamma_1$ we  find with $|t|\le
N$

$$|\pi\cot(\pi (N+1/2) + \pi it)|
=\pi\left|\frac{e^{i\pi (N+1/2) - \pi t}+e^{-i\pi (N+1/2) + \pi t}}
{e^{i\pi (N+1/2) - \pi t}-e^{-i\pi (N+1/2) + \pi t}}\right|
\\ = \pi\left|\frac{i(-1)^N e^{- \pi t} - i(-1)^N e^{\pi t}}
{i(-1)^N e^{- \pi t} + i(-1)^N e^{\pi t}}\right|
= \pi|\tanh(\pi t)|.$$

Observe that with $t$ real $\tanh(\pi t)$ has no poles and its norm is
bounded by one.  We thus get by ML the bound

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} 2N\pi / (N+1/2)^{2n} = 0$$

which  vanishes  as  required.   Continuing  with
$\Gamma_2$ we get for the norm of the trigonometric term (here $|t|\le
N+1/2$)

$$|\pi\cot(\pi t + \pi i N)|
= \pi\left|\frac{e^{i\pi t - \pi N} + e^{-i\pi t + \pi N}}
{e^{i\pi t - \pi N} - e^{-i\pi t + \pi N}}\right|
\le \pi\left|\frac{e^{\pi N}+e^{-\pi N}}{e^{\pi N}-e^{-\pi N}}\right|
=\pi|\coth(\pi N)|.$$

There aren't any  poles here either and this term  is bounded above by
$\pi\coth(\pi)$ because $N>1.$ Applying ML again yields

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} (2N+1) \pi\coth(\pi)/N^{2n}  = 0.$$

The  contribution from  $\Gamma_2$  vanishes as  well.  Hence we  have
justified the construction used above.

Comment: It looks okay, although I don't believe that $\cot (\pi z)$ has the bound you mentioned. You probably need to work harder to show that the integral goes to 0 as $R \to \infty$, by splitting up the circle into two pieces: one that $\cot$ has a nice bound, and one that is very short.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. At this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211372/proof-of-an-inequality-about-frac1z-sum-n-1-infty-frac2zz2-n/) I do show that $\cot(z)$ is bounded by a constant for $R$ large enough, by considering the upper and lower half plane separately. Of course as always in these kinds of summations and also in integral transform inversions the contours do not pass through the singularities. In the present case we could choose $R$ so that it passes halfway between consecutive poles on the real axis.

Comment: The bound I refer to applies to $|\cot(z)|$.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite see it. No matter what $R$ you choose there would be a small region, where $t$ (as in your link) is very close to 0, making your bound blow up. It's true though that such $t$ does not take up much space.

Comment: As an observation, if I were to post this now, I would use a rectangular rather than a circular contour.