# question about riemann zeta function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

How can one prove that

$$\zeta (2n)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}2^{2n-1}\pi ^{2n}B_{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ where $n\in N$

and how can one prove that $$\zeta (2n)=\frac{(-1)^{n}2^{2n-2}\pi ^{2n}E_{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!(2^{2n}-1)}$$ where $n\in N^*$

and $\zeta (x)$ is the [Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function),
$B_n$ a [Bernoulli number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number),
and $E_n$ an [Euler number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number)?

---

edit 2 after the comments: is there any link or book can give answer to my Question ?

Comment: Well, studying a lot about that wonderful function, its properties and stuff...I think such a question like yours should contain more background, self work, ideas, and not merely be shot out of the blue.

Comment: @DonAntonio so is there any link or book can give answer to my Question ?

Comment: Definitely you should check this: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~derek/qg/QuantCat/zeta2.pdf

Comment: There is a proof at this [Stackexchange post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248413/zeta-function-values-in-terms-of-bernoulli-numbers). You might want to replace the circular contour by a rectangular one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the product representation  $$\sin z = z \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{z^2}{(k\pi)^2}\right)$$, we obtain $$\log(\sin z) = \log z + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \log \left(1-\frac{z^2}{(k\pi)^2}\right)$$.

When differentiated, $$\cot z = \frac{1}{z} - \frac{2}{z} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{k\pi}\right)^{2n} = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{-2}{(k\pi)^{2n}} \, z^{2n-1}$$

By comparing coefficients with $$\cot z = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \frac{B_{2n} \, 2^{2n}}{(2n)!} \, z^{2n-1}$$, we obtain  $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k\pi)^{2n}} = (-1)^{n-1} \frac{B_{2n} \, 2^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}$$