# residue of $\frac{1}{z^{2n}} \pi \cot(\pi z)$ at $z=0$

Tags: residue-calculus

how to calculate the residue of  $$\frac{1}{z^{2n}} \pi \cot(\pi z)$$ at $z=0$

I know the answer is $$(2\pi i)^{2n} \frac{B_{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ but I dont know how

I saw an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248413/zeta-function-values-in-terms-of-bernoulli-numbers) using "[the coefficient extraction operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series)" but I dont know any thing about it

also I tried with $$ \sum_{m=0}^\infty B_{2m} (2\pi i)^{2m} \frac{z^{2m}}{(2m)!} =
\pi z \cot(\pi z).$$

but I faced many problem

so what is your suggest to solve the problem ?

Comment: What is your definition of the Bernoulli numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cot(z)$ can be expanded as
$$ \cot (z) = \frac 1z - \frac z 3  + \dots (-1)^n \frac{B_{2n}(2z)^{2n}}{(2n)! z}\dots $$
It follows from 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{B_n z^n}{n!} = \frac{z}{e^z-1} = \frac{z}{2}\left( \coth \left ( \frac z2 \right ) - 1\right)$$

The coefficient of $\displaystyle \frac 1 z$ in $\displaystyle \frac{1}{z^{2n}} \pi \cot(\pi z)$ would be $\displaystyle (-1)^n \frac{B_{2n}(2\pi)^{2n}}{(2n)! }$ which is your residue.