# Why do the even Bernoulli numbers grow so fast?

Tags: bernoulli-numbers

Question is in the title.

We have:

$$B_{2n} \sim (-1)^{n-1} 4 \sqrt {\pi n} \left( \frac n {\pi e} \right)^{2n}$$

Comment: $1<\zeta(2n)=(-1)^{n+1}B_{2n}(2\pi)^{2n}/(2\times(2n)!)$ (+ Stirling for $(2n)!$)

Comment: Given a generating function for a sequence, there is a method that relates the asymptotics of the sequence to properties of the function on the boundary of the disk of convergence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall the generating function
$$f(z) = \sum_{q\ge 0} B_q \frac{z^q}{q!} = \frac{z}{e^z-1}.$$

We can treat it as if it were rational as the poles are countable with
no accumulation point, so we may use the techniques of extracting coefficients from rational generating functions, with the asymptotics being given by inverse powers of the dominant poles.

The pole at $z=0$ is cancelled by the factor $z$ in the numerator. The
nearest two poles are at $\pm 2\pi i,$ both at the same distance from zero ($2\pi$).

Computing the residues we obtain
$$\mathrm{Res}(f(z); z=\pm 2\pi i) = \pm 2\pi i$$
and from this we get the singular decomposition
$$\frac{2\pi i}{z-2\pi i} - \frac{2\pi i}{z+2\pi i}.$$
Turn this into geometric series to get
$$\frac{1}{z/(2\pi i)-1} - \frac{1}{z/(2\pi i)+1}
= - \frac{1}{1-z/(2\pi i)} - \frac{1}{1+z/(2\pi i)}
\\= -\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{z^q}{(2\pi i)^q}
-\sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q \frac{z^q}{(2\pi i)^q}
= -2 \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{z^{2q}}{(2\pi i)^{2q}}
\\ = -2 \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q \frac{z^{2q}}{(2\pi)^{2q}}
= 2 \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^{q+1} \frac{z^{2q}}{(2\pi)^{2q}}.$$

Extracting coeffcients and since $B_{2n}  = (2n)! [z^{2n}] f(z)$ we find that
$$B_{2n} \sim (2n)! \times 2 \times 
\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2\pi)^{2n}}.$$
Using Stirling's formula this becomes
$$\sqrt{4\pi n} \left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}
\times 2 \times
\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2\pi)^{2n}}.$$
This is
$$4 \times (-1)^{n+1} \times \sqrt{\pi n} 
\left(\frac{n}{\pi e}\right)^{2n}.$$

**Addendum.** To  justify rigorously the above asymptotics  we need to
verify that  there isn't an additional entire  component not accounted
for in the complete singular decomposition.

To do this introduce the sum
$$g(w) = 
\sum_{q\ge 1}\left(\frac{1}{w/q-1}-\frac{1}{w/q+1}\right)
= 2 \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{1}{w^2/q^2-1}.$$

This  can  be  evaluated  using  a  [standard  technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112161/showing-sum-n-0-infty-frac13n13n2-frac-pi3-sqrt3)  from  complex
variables and setting
$$G(z) = 1/(w^2/z^2-1)\times\pi\cot(\pi z)$$
we have
$$g(w) = 
-
\left(
\mathrm{Res}(G(z); z=0)
+\mathrm{Res}(G(z); z=w)
+\mathrm{Res}(G(z); z=-w)
\right).$$
Computing the residues we get
$$g(w) = \pi w \cot(\pi w).$$
Now we claim that
$$f(z) = -\frac{1}{2}z + \sum_{q\ge 1} 
\left(\frac{2\pi i q}{z-2\pi i q}-\frac{2\pi i q}{z+2\pi i q}\right).$$
The sum is $g(z/(2\pi i))$ so we get
$$-\frac{1}{2}z + \frac{z}{2i}  \cot\left(\frac{z}{2i}\right)
= -\frac{1}{2}z + \frac{z}{2i}  \times i \times 
\frac{e^{z/2}+e^{-z/2}}{e^{z/2}-e^{-z/2}}
\\= \frac{1}{2} z
\left(-1 + \frac{e^z+1}{e^z-1}\right)
= \frac{1}{2}z \frac{2}{e^z-1} = \frac{z}{e^z-1}.$$

This shows  rigorously that the  entire part is  $$-\frac{1}{2}z$$ and
hence makes no  contribution to $B_{2n}$ where $n\ge  1$ and the above
singular decomposition is justified.

Comment: Thanks. This is way over my head! I just found out that it can be shown using the Riemann Zeta function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Asymptotic_approximation Can this be made rigorous? (only taking the first term from the Zeta series).

Comment: This is essentially what I have above, consult this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248413/zeta-function-values-in-terms-of-bernoulli-numbers) for more details. Some may prefer not to have the dependence on the zeta function values. You may however take more terms from Stirling's approximation as well as contributions from additional poles. (Signing off for the day.)