# An integer triangle for representing the Euler numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

We introduce a family of rational polynomials, for integer $n \ge 0$, as

$$ r_{n}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{ \sum_{j=0}^k x^j \binom{k}{j} (2j + 1)^n }{2^k}. $$

The formula for $r_{n}(x)$ is a variant of a well-known representation of the Euler numbers.
Let $\operatorname{E}_n(x)$ denote the Euler polynomials and let us agree to write
$ \operatorname{E}_n $ for $ 2^n \operatorname{E}_n(1/2) $.
We observe

$$ {r}_{n}(-1) = \operatorname{E}_n \quad (A122045). $$

This leads to the following infinite lower triangular integer matrix $\operatorname{T}$ for $0 \le k \le n$:
$$ \operatorname{T}(n, k) = 2^n  [x^k] r_{n}(x) $$

$$  1 $$
$$  3 \quad      3 $$
$$  7 \quad     36 \quad 25 $$
$$  15 \quad   297 \quad 625 \quad 343 $$
$$  31 \quad  2106 \quad 10000 \quad 14406 \quad 6561 $$
$$  63 \quad 13851 \quad 131250 \quad 369754 \quad 413343 \quad 161051 $$
$$  \ldots $$

The triangle has the first column $\operatorname{T}(n,0) = 2^{n + 1} - 1$,
and the main diagonal $ \operatorname{T}(n, n) = (2n + 1)^n$. But the key statement is

$$ \operatorname{E_n} = \frac{ \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \operatorname{T}(n, k) }{2^n}. $$

Such a representation of the Euler numbers suggests asking for a combinatorial interpretation of the $\operatorname{T}(n, k)$.

**Which combinatorial objects does $\operatorname{T}(n,k)$ count?**

Comment: A similar question regarding Bernoulli numbers was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4706827/).